tcsh piping ONLY stderr to null leaving stdout alone
running a tcsh in RHEL-8.10.
doing a grep -l <something> * I get a bunch of Is a directory responses.
in bash I would do  grep -l <something> * 2>/dev/null to suppress that.
What is the equivalent syntax in tcsh ?

From the tcsh man page:

The shell cannot presently redirect diagnostic output without also redirecting standard output, but (command > output-file) >& error-file is often an acceptable workaround. Either output-file or error-file may be /dev/tty to send output to the terminal.

If that workaround isn't feasible for whatever reason, consider switching to a different, more capable, shell.
